# Incorrectly reading large numbers from CSV with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I read various columns from a CSV a file and one of the columns is a 19 digit integer ID. If I just read it with no options, the number is read as float. It seems to be mangling the numbers.

For example the dataset has 100k unique ID values, but reading gives me 10k unique values. I changed the `read_csv` options to read it as string and the problem remains while it's being read as mathematical notation (eg: `*e^18`).

```py
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x)
df=pd.read_csv(file)
```

Comment: Do you try parameter `pd.read_csv(file, dtype={'col':str})` ? Or `pd.read_csv(file, dtype=str`) for all columns ?

Comment: Pandas 0.20.1 and windows 8.1

Comment: I did yes and the problem still remains. I get it as Mathematical Notation with both options.

Comment: Do you have a small example of a few rows of the CSV (perhaps obfuscating some fields if necessary) so that we can try to replicate this?

Answer (score 1):

Asked, it really happens when you read BigInteger value from .scv via pd.read_csv. For example:

```html
df = pd.read_csv('/home/user/data.csv', dtype=dict(col_a=str, col_b=np.int64))
# where both col_a and col_b contain same value: 107870610895524558
```

After reading following conditions are True:

```html
df.col_a == '107870610895524558'
df.col_a.astype(int) == 107870610895524558
# BUT
df.col_b == 107870610895524560
```

Thus I suggest that in case of reading big integers it is possible to read them as string and then convert column type to int

Answer (score 0):

Saving the column as "Number" format in csv/excel solved the problem for me. See [Microsoft's documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/available-number-formats-in-excel-0afe8f52-97db-41f1-b972-4b46e9f1e8d2).